# Инвертировать закругленный угол в CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, svg

У меня есть код css:

```
-moz-border-radius-topleft:50px;
```

Я получаю результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли какие-либо возможности сделать вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перевод вопроса: [Invert rounded corner in CSS? @Mubeen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4012085/7394871)

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012085/invert-rounded-corner-in-css/36601898#36601898

Comment: А не вариант задать это с помощью псевдоэлемента? Белый круг с абсолютным позиционированием

Comment: Я передумал. Это будет работать только с заранее известным фоновым цветом. Так что это не вариант

Comment: http://codepen.io/alexeyten/pen/wJjgML?editors=1100 можно использовать `border-image`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С 2010 года прошло достаточно много времени и уже можно использовать `border-image`.

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #acf, #afc) 0 0 / 33px 33px;
}

.fancy-border {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 40px solid transparent;
  border-image-source: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 60 60' width='120' height='120'%3E%3Cpath d='m 0 10a10 10 0 0 0 10-10h40a10 10 0 0 0 10 10v40a10 10 0 0 0-10 10h-40a10 10 0 0 0-10-10z' fill='%23fcc' fill-opacity='.6'/%3E%3Cpath d='m5 15a15 15 0 0 0 10-10h30a15 15 0 0 0 10 10v30a15 15 0 0 0-10 10h-30a15 15 0 0 0-10-10z' fill='none' stroke='%23fff'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  border-image-slice: 40 fill;
  border-image-width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fancy-border">Привет</div>
```

Ответ скопирован с https://toster.ru/q/409258#answer_992741

Answer (score 4):

Вы также можете использовать и [inline svg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction) и [path element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths)

```css
body{background:url('http://i.imgur.com/RECDV24.jpg');background-size:cover;}
svg{width:30%;}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 10 10">
  <path d="M9 1 V9 H1 V3 Q3 3 3 1" fill="#fff"/>
</svg>
```

В этом примере я использую [кубическую кривую Безье](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Bezier_Curves) для инвертированного круглого края.

При таком подходе вы также можете заполнить форму **изображением или градиентом:**

```css
body{background:url('http://i.imgur.com/RECDV24.jpg');background-size:cover;}
svg{width:30%;}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 10 6.7">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip">
      <path d="M9 1 V6.7 H1 V3 Q3 3 3 1" fill="#fff"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <image xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/qi5FGET.jpg" x="0" y="0" height="6.7" width="10" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>
</svg>
```

Перевод ответа: [Invert rounded corner in CSS? @web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36601898/7394871)

Answer (score 4):

Вариант с использованием `radial-gradient`

```css
body{
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/RECDV24.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
div{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;   
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 0 0, transparent 28px, tomato 28px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Вариант с использованием `box-shadow`

```css
body {
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/RECDV24.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

div {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;  
}
div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px tomato;  
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: вот, что значит творческий подход! Я не стал добавлять вариант ответа - http://stackoverflow.com/a/19572673/7394871 потому-что он не работал в FF, вы заменили -webkit-mask-image: на background-image:  и теперь работает в FF (+)

Comment: Некрасивые зазубрины есть.

Comment: @Sasha Omelchenko да есть такое, устранить не смог

Answer (score 1):

Еще одно решение, но им лучше не пользоваться

```
body {
  background: #fff;
}
.black-square {
  position: relative;
  background: #000;
  width:100px;
  height:100px
}
.black-square:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border: solid #FFF;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    clip: rect(auto auto 15px 15px);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    top: -16px;
    left:-16px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7wepem63/3/